# How to build Notepad++ 5.8.7 from its source

Tags: c++, notepad++

Basically i want to modify auto complete syntax functionality in notepad++. I want to know how to build it using it source code.

Comment: 1) Learn C++ 2) Download the source 3) Get a compiler, or use Visual C++ if it's distributed as a VC++ solution 4) Work.

Comment: What does it's documentation say about building it? I suggest you read that first...

Comment: @BoltClock: knowing C++ wasn't a requirement to build C++-written software last time I checked.

Comment: @rubenvb: He wants to modify part of the code. It's essential that he knows something.

Comment: @BoltClock: wow, ok, I thought somebody trying to modify source code would know how to read/find the project's build documentation.

Comment: @rubenvb: Thought so too; apparently that's not always the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a friend called Google. He told me to look here:

[http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Notepad%2B%2B#Build_Notepad.2B.2B_v5.8.7_.28win32.2C_Debug.29:](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Notepad%2B%2B#Build_Notepad.2B.2B_v5.8.7_.28win32.2C_Debug.29%3a)